# React-native-video: Detect if module is running in Swift and change orientation

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-video

I'm using different native SDK's in my react-native app, and I'm controlling the device orientation based on what module is loaded.
In my AppDelegate.swift I have the following

```
  var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
      return self.orientationLock
  }
  
  struct AppUtility {
      static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
          if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
              delegate.orientationLock = orientation
          }
      }

      static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
          self.lockOrientation(orientation)
          UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
      }
  }
```

This works fine when I have my own ViewControllers where I can do the following:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

      let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
      UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
      AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft)
```

However when I'm using the react-native package react-native-video-controls (https://github.com/itsnubix/react-native-video-controls) (or react-native-video) I cannot find a way to detect that it's running from swift and unlock the device orientation

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Ps. I have tried to use (https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker) but it cannot override the Orientation when it is set from AppDelegate

Comment: Why can't you override the orientation? What are you seeing the in the console?

Comment: In the xcode console it says: ```Unlocking All Orientations```, but the screen itself cannot rotate.